# How to use Krusader to avoid useless taking space on displays?

Tags: 18.04, display, krusader

Krusader Version 2.6.0 "Stiff Challenges" takes up too much space on the displays, because it uses long buttons with text instead of icons in both panel toolbars, in the same row as both the paths.

[image]
Previous version 2.4.0-beta3 "Single Step" had only icons there.

**Isn't this some fault of my installation?** (The first desperate idea was to retain the old version and prevent Krusader from updating.)

Comment: I don't know the `krusader` program (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=krusader), but it sounds like you already rolled back to an old version, which you could likely keep using `apt-mark hold` to prevent it being upgraded again.. however this will likely create issues in the future (esp. *release-upgrade* time, if not sooner)  I've not evaluated the dependencies of https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/krusader to see any issues though (I would before I did it!)   ie. if you get a solution without the rollback, I'd opt for that & not what I've suggested

Comment: What do you mean by "long banners instead of icons"? Can you provide an image to illustrate the issue? I have *Stiff Challenges* and don't see / understand the "long banner" issue.

Comment: @guiverc: Thanks, too! I have added the picture. I'd like to use the newer version, e.g.  if it better compares both directories. I don't see a similar question in the Krusader forum.

Comment: @DK Bose: I have corrected the question. In the Krusader Version 2.6.0 "Stiff Challenges", you do not have the long buttons with the text 'This button toggles the sync-browse mode. When active ... panel - if possible.' and 'Open the folder history list' and 'BookMan ...'? In the previous version of Krusader, instead of the texts, there were icons at the buttons and such texts were there only as tool-tips.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this button does not show an icon but only text, since I never used it. But if you want to disable it, do the following:

- Go to Settings -> Configure Krusader...
- Go to Panel - Buttons
- At the bottom you can enable / disable "Visible Panel Toolbar buttons"

Most probably you have "Toggle-button for sync-browsing" enabled, which is the one that takes up all the space.

I do not have icons for this, Folder History or Bookman either in this version by the way.

Comment: Thanks, however I use all that buttons, I don't wish to disable them. In that settings, I see things like 'Toolbar buttons have icons' and I hope that there is some possibility to set it which I have not found. For a project of this kind, one does not assume that this is a mistake by developers who mistaken the tooltip instead of the icon.

Comment: Ok, then you could try this: Delete the file ~/.cache/icon-cache.kcache, select a different Icon theme in the system settings, and then restart Krusader. It appears that in some themes the icons for those buttons don't exist, probably the theme you used got changed during a recent update.

Comment: Thanks, I have renamed the file ~/.cache/icon-cache.kcache and, by running Krusader again, the system has created another file with the same name. I do not know how to 'select a different Icon theme in the system settings'. 
Specifically: Instead of the texts 'This button toggles the sync-browse mode. When active ... panel - if possible.' and 'Open the folder history list' and 'BookMan ...' in the Krusader, I'd like to use (maybe my own) icons; if it is possible by direct setting, please advise me, how to set it. (I would like to avoid working with the Krusader source text.)

Comment: I don't know plain Ubuntu very well, but I guess the icon theme should be somewhere under "Appearance" in the settings. Krusader uses system-wide icon themes, so I'm not sure you can add specific icons on your own. Remember that you need to delete the icon-cache.kcache file and restart Krusader each time you change the icon theme, or it will not show a change.